# Logo sizing while in mobile

Tags: css, image, mobile

I have attached an image to help explain what I am trying to accomplish. I would like to have my logo to display similar to the image when viewed in mobile. Not sure if it is some padding that is causing it to sit above and not horizontal to the menu tab.

Website address is https://chris-schilling-jksc.squarespace.com/

Password is fsj

[image]

Comment: Remove the `height: 85px;` for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displaying horizontal only. but what I feel is, you have set a `height`. Might help if you remove that style.

```css
#header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

And also it is better to combine it with the `@media` queries for mobile if it works for the desktop.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    #header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage {
      width: 350px;
      height: auto;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width:640px) {
    #header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage {
      width: 350px;
      height: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the logo to auto instead of 85px.

```
#header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    #header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The problem was that height was being defined which cause it to appear large.

Answer (score 0):

You have a height set for `#header #logoWrapper, #header #logoImage` --- leave it at auto and the elements will align based on their `display: inline-block` `vertical-align: middle`

I just checked it in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@media (max-width:640px){

  #logoImage a {
    margin-top:20px;
  }

}
```

NOTE: Don't make the logo bigger because iPhone's width is 320px. If you increase the size of logo, then that menu icon will be disappear on mobile.